# How to convert accelerometer sensor data to step counter?

Tags: dart, flutter, accelerometer, sensors, uiaccelerometer

I want to build a step counter widget with flutter but don't know how can I convert the accelerometer sensor data of X, Y and Z axis to the step counter with the help of sensor flutter package.

Comment: does the plugin implements step data  for android sensor api and ios healthkit?

Comment: @Tree no the plugin does't provides any implementation regarding steps. Have a look at the link https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sensors

Comment: than you would need to fork the plugin to get the data, or write your own. Maybe ask the owner if he wants to do it

Comment: Can you share any of the plugin link which could work with flutter

Comment: there is none. Check the accelerometer plugin and see if you can modify it for flutter

Answer (score -1):

I think trying to do this accurately from accelerometer data may be tricky, so you may be better trying to do it natively in a plugin. For example, Android has a Step Counter sensor type:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

If you insist on doing it from the accelerometer data, I think you probably want to count the direction changes (count every other one), but I expect making it accurate (eg. trying to ignore things that aren't steps) will be non-trivial.